# How do I handle infinite price values when forecasting price?

Tags: forecasting

I have monthly revenue data and monthly units sold data. I don't have price data. I calculate price by dividing monthly revenue by monthly units sold. Units data isn't always recorded, even if there is revenue, so I sometimes end up with revenue being divided by 0 units. This results in an infinite value for price. My overall goal is to forecast price and units then multiply those forecasts together to get the revenue forecast. How should I handle infinite values when I am forecasting price? Should I just replace them all with null?

Comment: It is an error to treat a missing value as zero.  Correcting that error will make the infinite values disappear.

Comment: I appreciate your help, thank you!